# How to save LocalDate to Postgres with Payara Micro

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, eclipselink, payara-micro

I am getting the below error when I try to persist a LocalDate column. The error only occurs when the field is null. The publish_date column is of type Date in the database.

I check [Bug 535431](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535431) and [Bug 546312](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546312) and apparently the issue is supposed to have been resolved with version 2.7.6 but it is still occurring.

Error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "publish_date" is of type date but expression is of type character varying
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "publish_date")
    private LocalDate publishDate;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around to this. I added `&amp;stringtype=unspecified` to the end of the JDBC-URL but I am not sure what the issue is:

```
<url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library?currentSchema=books&amp;stringtype=unspecified</url>
```